# getting distinct result with few more conditions in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hai i have some sample data

```
 bookId     | bookPnr       | bookDate   | bookFullName | bookMobile | bookEmail         | bookSource
 9876543210 | BPT1100000000 | 2018-11-18 | User 1       | 9876543210 | test@gmail.com    | Redbus
 9876543211 | BPT1100000001 | 2017-11-18 | User 2       | 9876543211 | testOne@gmail.com | Redbus
 9876543212 | BPT1100000002 | 2017-11-18 | User 3       | 9876543214 | testtwo@gmail.com | TicketGoose
```

I need a result like

```
Mobile      | 2018 | 2017 | 2016 | Redbus | TicketGoose | total

9876543210  |  2   | 3    | 6    | 2      | 2           | 11
9876543211  |  1   | 1    | 1    | 2      | 1           | 3
```

So i need distinct mobile numbers based on year and source 
 I did query something like,

```
SELECT count(bookId), bookMobile, bookDate, bookSource FROM `booking_info` 
GROUP by bookMobile, MONTH(bookDate), bookSource ORDER BY bookMobile DESC
```

Is it possible to do it with single query or we have to use PHP Any suggetions will be really appreciated.

Comment: MySQL  <> SQL server. Please specify which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: add  a proper data sample  .. coherent with your  expected result

Comment: data sample updated

Comment: How many distinct BookSources are there? single digit? tens? more than tens? or do you just want `Redbus | TicketGoose` ?

Comment: You are showing values for 2016 and 2017, but there is no `bookDate` for either of these years in the sample data. Please ensure that the sample data should match the expected output.

Comment: most probably single digits but may exceed

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i have only bookDate it contains year month and day i have to filter year from that only

Comment: Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "conditional aggregates" to "pivot" your data. Basically this means placing a case expression inside an aggregation function. Here I have used COUNT():

```
SELECT
    bookMobile
  , count(case when year(bookDate) = 2016 then 1 end) as `2016`
  , count(case when year(bookDate) = 2017 then 1 end) as `2017`
  , count(case when year(bookDate) = 2018 then 1 end) as `2018`
  , count(case when bookSource = 'Redbus' then 1 end) as Redbus
  , count(case when bookSource = 'TicketGoose' then 1 end) as TicketGoose
FROM booking_info
GROUP BY
    bookMobile
ORDER BY
    bookMobile DESC
```